# 500 internal server error in SharePoint

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, server, sharepoint-2013

I'm getting a

> '500 internal server error'

while trying to access any web application other than the central administrator page.This problem rise up suddenly on a  day when I tried opening it.No password change have been made on the server side,also I have verified all the application pool are in the started state only.I have checked by creatinga new webapplication still the same issue occurs.I  have also tried by changing the identity of the specific web application from **IIS**,but it does'nt works.I was not able to set the user name and password for identity over the advanced settings of **SecurityTokenServiceApplicationPoolService** in the application pool as it is saying 'invalid credentials'.Please help me to solve this issue.SharePoint is installed on **SQLServer 2008R2**. When I checked the **Event viewer** I'm getting two warnings and two errors.Two errors saying `

> claims Authentication(8306) and warnings as configuration(8059)

`.(*I know this Question is asked in the in the SharePoint community but the answers doesn't solve my issue,so that  I'm asking it here*)

Comment: Onen Event viewer. Under windows -> check application logs (first clear all logs. then open your web application in browser. Refresh logs). Please add any message / error you get in it.

Comment: I'm getting two warnings and two  errors.Two errors saying claims Authentication(8306) and warnings as configuration(8059) @love thakker

Comment: can you add them in your question?

Comment: Added this errors also @lovethakker

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/2520344 try it.

Comment: Please, check the step by step guide at **[SharePoint: 500 Internal Server Error](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/500-internal-server-error-in-sharepoint-2013/)**